# Azure Function will not import Powershell Modules

Tags: powershell, azure-functions

Been tearing out my hair trying to figure out what is wrong with this but I am at a loss. I am really not sure what changed, this function app was working a few days ago.

host.json

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "extensionBundle": {
        "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
        "version": "[3.3.0, 4.0.0)"
    }
}
```

Requirements.psd1

```
# This file enables modules to be automatically managed by the Functions service.
# See https://aka.ms/functionsmanageddependency for additional information.
#
@{
    # For latest supported version, go to 'https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Az'. 
    # To use the Az module in your function app, please uncomment the line below.
     'Az' = '7.1.0'
     'Az.Accounts' = '2.2.3'
     'Az.Storage' = '5.10.1'
     'Az.Keyvault' = '3.3.0'
}
```

Profile.ps1

```
# Azure Functions profile.ps1
#
# This profile.ps1 will get executed every "cold start" of your Function App.
# "cold start" occurs when:
#
# * A Function App starts up for the very first time
# * A Function App starts up after being de-allocated due to inactivity
#
# You can define helper functions, run commands, or specify environment variables
# NOTE: any variables defined that are not environment variables will get reset after the first execution

# Authenticate with Azure PowerShell using MSI.
# Remove this if you are not planning on using MSI or Azure PowerShell.
if ($env:MSI_SECRET) {
    Disable-AzContextAutosave -Scope Process | Out-Null
    Connect-AzAccount -Identity
}

Import-Module Az -RequiredVersion "7.1.0"
Import-Module Az.Keyvault -RequiredVersion "3.3.0"
Import-Module Az.Accounts -RequiredVersion "2.2.3"
Import-Module Az.Storage -RquiredVersion "5.10.1"


# Uncomment the next line to enable legacy AzureRm alias in Azure PowerShell.
# Enable-AzureRmAlias

# You can also define functions or aliases that can be referenced in any of your PowerShell functions.
```

Error Messages

```
[Warning] The Function app may be missing a module containing the 'Disable-AzContextAutosave' command definition

[Warning] The Function app may be missing a module containing the 'Connect-AzAccount' command definition.

[Error] ERROR: The term 'Disable-AzContextAutosave' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.

[Warning] The Function app may be missing a module containing the 'Get-AzKeyVaultSecret' command definition.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a good chance that there's some dependency issues with the specific and required versions of the modules you're using.

e.g. `Az` is now at `10.4.1`

Version of `Az` that you're specifying of `7.1.0` https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Az/7.1.0 has the following dependencies listed:

Az.Accounts (>= 2.7.1)
Your Function: 2.2.3

Az.KeyVault (= 4.2.0)
Your Function: 3.3.0

Az.Storage (= 4.1.1)
Your Function: 5.10.1

#### Remove Az completely from `requirements.psd1`

It is recommended that you don't import all of the `Az` module. Removing this will increase performance on cold starts.

As you're importing the `Az` it will import it's own depdencies as part of the module loading which may be conflicting.

If you can't upgrade to a major version of a specific module then you can pin it to the latest minor version using the `'2.*'` syntax in the `requirements.psd1`

Comment: I removed the az statement and that did the trick thankyou!